# AngularJs, troublesome filter function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS but got stuck on my filter function.

I have a JSON file containing persons and a service & controller that loads it.

```
[{
"id": "000000-0000",
"name": "John Doe"
 },
 ...
```

So far so good, then in my form which is connected to person.id & person.name I would like to be able to pick the current person using a searchbox. I created a inputfield named searchText and wrote a searchFilter function. I would like to set the $scope.person to match the searchText criteria so that it updates my inputboxes (person.name, person.id with the corresponding values.

```
 .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'Persons', function($scope, Persons) {
    $scope.persons = Persons.query();

    $scope.searchFilter = function(obj) {
       var p = new RegExp($scope.searchText, 'i');
       $scope.person = ????
            };

        }])
```

How could that be done? By applying the same filter to every single input?
Regards

UPDATE: To clarify, if the searchText matches none or several posts, the form remains empty. If and when it matches a unique post, this post become $scope.person and the form is filled with the persons values

Comment: create simple demo showing how you want to use this

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a built-in filter in Angular that does that for you. It's called 'filter'. So keeping your search field as `searchText`, just write your ng-repeat as

```
ng-repeat="person in persons | filter:searchText"
```

Pretty simple really.

Edit: from Angular docs http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

Comment: doesn't really accomplish what OP wanted, to populate other `ng-model` binding

Comment: True, that one works, but I don't have any ng-repeaters, I have a form hooked up with person.name, person.id and so on.. Can't really understand how I will update my $scope.person using my filter..

Comment: @elwis You don't necessarily have to use `ng-repeat`. You can use the filter in your controller as `$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)`. So bind your $scope.persons to the array (the first argument in $filter), and simply modify the expression/comparator by passing in the searchfield text. $filter will simply return a new array with the filtered values

Comment: Uh Ok, so how exactly do you want this $scope.person to work? What if your searchText doesn't match any results, what if it matches more than one person? This is unclear, either post some more of your code or explain what you want better.

Comment: @trekforever, I'm not OP, but from his last comment I think he doesn't want $scope.person(s) to be an array as he is using it in a form. Surely OP will clarify.

Comment: @NicolasMoise, yes youre right. I load my "Persons" array from my JSON (for now, this is a prototype) and then I would like my $scope.person to match what is written in the "searchText". If it matches none or more then one the form will remain empty. But as soon as it matches a personalId (these ones are unique) so that there's only one possible hit the form will show the record

Comment: @elwis OK, this is clearer then. I'd start out by having a $scope.$watch on searchText then check if the new value matches any in your persons array (regEx maybe, I dunno) and then changing $scope.person if a single match is found. If I have some free time today I can try to write out a more fleshed-out solution.

Comment: @elwis You might even be able to use the built-in "filter" filter (and checking that the length of filtered array is 1) so you don't have to do all that annoying regEx stuff yourself.

Comment: @NicolasMoise, thanks, i would gladly skip the RegExp stuff, I never fell in love with Lisp & Perl and the others ;) keeping an eye on the length of the array sounds like a great idea, I think I'll try that path

Answer (score 0):

actApp.directive('locinput', ['composite', 'component', function (composite, component){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template:"",

```
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs){
        //Add the element to the main components collection
        $scope.components.push($element);

        var compileTag;
        var htmlTag;

        htmlTag= "<input3p id='inputTxt"+$attrs.index+"' chars='"+$attrs.chars+"' index='"+$attrs.index+"' answer='"+$attrs.answer+"' size='"+$attrs.size+"'></input3p>"
        compileTag = component.getCompiledTag($scope, htmlTag);
        $element.append(compileTag);

        htmlTag = "<label3p id='correctText' text='answer["+$attrs.answer+"], question[7]' class='correctText'></label3p>";
        compileTag = component.getCompiledTag($scope, htmlTag)
        $element.append(compileTag);

        $scope.$on(SUBMISSION, function (event, correct) {
            $('.input3p').attr("disabled", true);
             $("#submit3p").css({"pointer-events":"none"});
             $("#submit3p").attr("disabled",true);

            if(!correct){
                $('.correctText').css({visibility: 'visible'});
                $('#redDivide').css({visibility: 'visible'});
                $element[0].show['cross']();
            }else{
                $element[0].show['tick']();
            }
        });

        $element.bind("keydown", function (event) {  
             if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
          });

        component.annunciator($scope, $element, $attrs, 'tick');
        component.annunciator($scope, $element, $attrs, 'cross');
        component.position($scope, $element, $attrs);
        component.size($scope, $element, $attrs);
    }
}
```

}]);